# Pthread vs Work Queue in Linux

Tags: c, linux, kernel, driver

I am trying to sync two operations in a Linux driver I have created. In essence, I need to use the DMAEngine to perform functions on two different DMA channels, one that is used for sending data and one used for receiving it. Currently, in my driver, I am able send data from the send channel to the receive channel over DMA.

This internal driver test looks like this

```
#define TEST_SIZE 1024

struct dma_proxy_channel_interface {
    unsigned char buffer[TEST_SIZE];
    enum proxy_status { PROXY_NO_ERROR = 0, PROXY_BUSY = 1, PROXY_TIMEOUT = 2, PROXY_ERROR = 3 } status;
    unsigned int length;
};

struct dma_proxy_channel {
    struct dma_proxy_channel_interface *interface_p;    /* user to kernel space interface */
    dma_addr_t interface_phys_addr;         

    struct device *proxy_device_p;              /* character device support */
    struct device *dma_device_p;
    dev_t dev_node;
    struct cdev cdev;
    struct class *class_p;

    struct dma_chan *channel_p;             /* dma support */
    struct completion cmp;
    dma_cookie_t cookie;
    dma_addr_t dma_handle;
    u32 direction;                      /* DMA_MEM_TO_DEV or DMA_DEV_TO_MEM */
};

static struct dma_proxy_channel channels[2];


static void tx_test(struct work_struct *unused)
{
    transfer(&channels[0]);
}
static void test(void)
{
    int i;
    const int test_size = 1024;
    struct work_struct work;

    /* Initialize the transmit buffer with a pattern and then start
     * the seperate thread of control to handle the transmit transfer
     * since the functions block waiting for the transfer to complete.
     */
    for (i = 0; i < test_size; i++) {
        channels[0].interface_p->buffer[i] = i;
    }

    channels[0].interface_p->length = test_size;

    INIT_WORK(&work, tx_test);
    schedule_work(&work);

    /* Initialize the receive buffer with zeroes so that we can be sure
     * the transfer worked, then start the receive transfer.
     */
    for (i = 0; i < test_size; i++) {
        channels[1].interface_p->buffer[i] = 0;
    }

    channels[1].interface_p->length = test_size;
    transfer(&channels[1]);

    /* Verify the receiver buffer matches the transmit buffer to 
     * verify the transfer was good
     */
    for (i = 0; i < test_size; i++) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "tx: %d\trx: %d\n", channels[0].interface_p->buffer[i], channels[1].interface_p->buffer[i]);

        if (channels[0].interface_p->buffer[i] !=
            channels[1].interface_p->buffer[i])
            printk("buffer not equal, index = %d\n", i);
    }
}
```

The transfer function includes calls to the DMAEngine that perform not only the transfer but much of the setup for the channel. These functions include dma_map_single, dmaengine_prep_slave_single, setting callback for channel, init_completion, dmaengine_submit, dma_async_issue_pending, wait_for_completion_timeout, and dma_async_is_tx_complete.

From what I understand, these functions need to be executed at nearly the same time for each channel to be ready to interact with the other. Using the work queue in the driver is able to accomplish this.

Now the issue is that when I create a character device driver to do this, each of the channels has their own device file. The structure is such that, an mmap is performed for each channel so that the buffer and length properties of the dma_proxy_channel->interface_p can be set and changed from the user space for each channel. Then an ioctl call is made which essentially takes the private data from the character driver which was set by mmap and pumps it into the transfer function you see called above. Indeed, these calls too must be synced. In the example I received, the author tried to use pthread to sync the ioctl calls. Here is his code.

```
static struct dma_proxy_channel_interface *tx_proxy_interface_p;
static int tx_proxy_fd;
/* The following function is the transmit thread to allow the transmit and the 
 * receive channels to be operating simultaneously. The ioctl calls are blocking
 * such that a thread is needed.
 */
void *tx_thread()
{
    int dummy, i;

    /* Set up the length for the DMA transfer and initialize the transmit
     * buffer to a known pattern.
     */
    tx_proxy_interface_p->length = TEST_SIZE;

        for (i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; i++)
            tx_proxy_interface_p->buffer[i] = i;

    /* Perform the DMA transfer and the check the status after it completes
     * as the call blocks til the transfer is done.
     */
    printf("tx ioctl user space\n");
    ioctl(tx_proxy_fd, 0, &dummy);

    if (tx_proxy_interface_p->status != PROXY_NO_ERROR)
        printf("Proxy tx transfer error\n");
}

/* The following function uses the dma proxy device driver to perform DMA transfers
 * from user space. This app and the driver are tested with a system containing an
 * AXI DMA without scatter gather and with transmit looped back to receive.
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    struct dma_proxy_channel_interface *rx_proxy_interface_p;
    int rx_proxy_fd, i;
    int dummy;
    pthread_t tid;

    printf("DMA proxy test\n");

    /* Step 1, open the DMA proxy device for the transmit and receive channels with
     * read/write permissions
     */     

    tx_proxy_fd = open("/dev/dma_proxy_tx", O_RDWR);

    if (tx_proxy_fd < 1) {
        printf("Unable to open DMA proxy device file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    rx_proxy_fd = open("/dev/dma_proxy_rx", O_RDWR);
    if (tx_proxy_fd < 1) {
        printf("Unable to open DMA proxy device file\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Step 2, map the transmit and receive channels memory into user space so it's accessible
     */
    tx_proxy_interface_p = (struct dma_proxy_channel_interface *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct dma_proxy_channel_interface), 
                                    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, tx_proxy_fd, 0);

    printf("tx_proxy_interface_p: %p\n", (void*)tx_proxy_interface_p);

    rx_proxy_interface_p = (struct dma_proxy_channel_interface *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct dma_proxy_channel_interface),
                                    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, rx_proxy_fd, 0);

        printf("rx_proxy_interface_p: %p\n", (void*)rx_proxy_interface_p);

        if ((rx_proxy_interface_p == MAP_FAILED) || (tx_proxy_interface_p == MAP_FAILED)) {
            printf("Failed to mmap\n");
            return -1;
        }

    /* Create the thread for the transmit processing and then wait a second so the printf output is not 
     * intermingled with the receive processing
     */
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, tx_thread, NULL);    
    sleep(1);

    /* Initialize the receive buffer so that it can be verified after the transfer is done
     * and setup the size of the transfer for the receive channel
     */ 
    for (i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; i++)
        rx_proxy_interface_p->buffer[i] = 0;

        rx_proxy_interface_p->length = TEST_SIZE;
    printf("rx_proxy_interface_p->length: %d\n", rx_proxy_interface_p->length); 
    /* Step 3, Perform the DMA transfer and after it finishes check the status 
     */

    printf("rx ioctl user space\n");
    ioctl(rx_proxy_fd, 0, &dummy);

    if (rx_proxy_interface_p->status != PROXY_NO_ERROR)
        printf("Proxy rx transfer error\n");

    /* Verify the data recieved matchs what was sent (tx is looped back to tx)
     */
    for (i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("tx: %d\trx: %d\n", tx_proxy_interface_p->buffer[i], rx_proxy_interface_p->buffer[i]);
//          if (tx_proxy_interface_p->buffer[i] !=
  //                rx_proxy_interface_p->buffer[i])
    //              printf("buffer not equal, index = %d\n", i);
        }

    /* Unmap the proxy channel interface memory and close the device files before leaving
     */
    munmap(tx_proxy_interface_p, sizeof(struct dma_proxy_channel_interface));
    munmap(rx_proxy_interface_p, sizeof(struct dma_proxy_channel_interface));

    close(tx_proxy_fd);
    close(rx_proxy_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

You notice he used pthread_create and sleep to try to sync the ioctl calls. Oddly enough, the data for the rx_proxy_interface_p, which is set in the user space before the second ioctl call is not being mapped to the kernel space. When the ioctl call is made, the private data for the character driver associated to that channel has not been changed.

My question is why is it that in the kernel space, the work queue seems  to synchronize the calls to the transfer function for these channels, but in the user space, when using threading, mmapped locations in the kernel space are not being changed? What performance differences should I expect to see between using the work queue and threading libraries?